# need help to create regular expression

Tags: regex

i need regular expression which is not allow &#39

Comment: What's the *actual* problem you are trying to solve? Perhaps SQL injection? If so, then there are certainly better solutions than what you're proposing.

Comment: Yes, please give more detail on what you want to do and why.  That will get you the best possible answer.

Comment: i try this and it solved my problem

^[\s\w&#33;&#34;&#35;&#36;&#37;&#38;&#39;&#40;&#41;&#42;&#43;&#44;&#45;&#46;&#60;&#61;&#62;&#63;.]{0,450}$

Answer (score 2):

If you want to say "match any character but zzz," use [^].

`[^']+` will match one or more characters, up until it hits a '.

If you want to make sure the entire string does not contain the specified character:

```
^[^']*$
```

Answer (score 1):

This will match only strings that do not contain a single quotation mark (your question is very unspecific so I have no idea if that's what you want, please be as specific as possible and describe what you really want to do):

```
/^[^']*$/
```